# PHP multiple file upload problems

Tags: php, file-upload

Ok so I have a form that has a multiple file input. When i submit the form the files are not uploaded. can anyone help. thank you in advance. If you need any more info let me know...

HTML:

```
<input type="file" multiple="mulitple" id="image_file[]" name="image_file[]" />
```

PHP:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$target_path = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/uploads/portfolio-images/';
$target_file = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['image_file']['name']);
foreach ($_FILES['image_file']['error'] as $key => $error) {
      if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmp_name = $_FILES['image_file']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $name = $_FILES['image_file']['name'][$key];
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path)){
            echo 'uploaded';
        }
        else {
            echo 'failed';
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does basic debugging tell you. Does `if (isset($_POST['submit']))` ever fire? What does the `$_FILES` array contain? (`print_r($_FILES)`)

Comment: Are any of the files getting uploaded? Are you sure the directory exists (wp-content/uploads/portfolio-images)? Does your form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` set?

Comment: apologies. ok so print_r $files shows nothing. yes the directory exists and yes i have multipart/form-data. I had it working with a single file upload. I want to be able to upload the multiple files and add their names to a database eventually.

Comment: This could be anything from a wrong variable (typo) to a lack of write permissions in the destination folder. Your code itself seems fine, but there's no way to be sure until you check your web servers' error log for further details.

Comment: I think it may be the fact that you named your file input image_file[] instead of image_file. However I may be wrong since i never used file arrays before.

Comment: ok so i retried print_r $_FILES and got this

Comment: Array ( [image_file] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ad.jpg [1] => arrows.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpSdVUHh [1] => /tmp/phpZvPxIg ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 8320 [1] => 38254 ) ) ) failedArray ( [image_file] => Array ( [name] => Array ( [0] => ad.jpg [1] => arrows.png ) [type] => Array ( [0] => image/jpeg [1] => image/png ) [tmp_name] => Array ( [0] => /tmp/phpSdVUHh [1] => /tmp/phpZvPxIg ) [error] => Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 0 ) [size] => Array ( [0] => 8320 [1] => 38254 ) ) ) fail

Comment: Can anyone else shed any light on this